# '&' requires l-value, /permissive doesnt work anymore

Tags: c++

I have this problem with adding/combining vectors which returns the "'&' requires l-value". I read other's issues with this but still cannot understand fully what am I doing wrong.
Here is where it's giving the error:
`auto c = add(&CAM::GET_CAM_COORD(cam), &multiply(&rot_to_direction(&rot), speed));`
And these are the methods

```
Vector3 add(Vector3* vectorA, Vector3* vectorB) {
        Vector3 result;
        result.x = vectorA->x;
        result.y = vectorA->y;
        result.z = vectorA->z;
        result.x += vectorB->x;
        result.y += vectorB->y;
        result.z += vectorB->z;
        return result;
    }
```

and

```
Vector3 multiply(Vector3* vector, float x) {
        Vector3 result;
        result.x = vector->x;
        result.y = vector->y;
        result.z = vector->z;
        result.x *= x;
        result.y *= x;
        result.z *= x;
        return result;
    }
```

and

```
Vector3 rot_to_direction(Vector3* rot) {
        float radiansZ = rot->z * 0.0174532924f;
        float radiansX = rot->x * 0.0174532924f;
        float num = abs((float)cos((double)radiansX));
        Vector3 dir;
        dir.x = (float)((double)((float)(-(float)sin((double)radiansZ))) * (double)num);
        dir.y = (float)((double)((float)cos((double)radiansZ)) * (double)num);
        dir.z = (float)sin((double)radiansX);
        return dir;
    }
```

CAM::GET_CAM_COORD(cam) also returns Vector3
Vector3 in my project is just a struct with 3 ints, x,y,z.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't take a pointer to a temporary. Is there a reason your functions don't just take const references instead?

Comment: Here the best solution is to change the function signature to avoid pointers and use reference

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 multiply(Vector3* vector, float x)  { ... }
```

Returns a temporary `Vector3`. You try to take the address of a temporary object in

```
                                       V     
auto c = add(&CAM::GET_CAM_COORD(cam), &multiply(&rot_to_direction(&rot), speed));
```

That's not allowed. You could simply change `multiply` and `add` to take a const reference instead of a pointer:

```
Vector3 multiply(const Vector3 &vector, float x) { ... }
```

And call them appropriately:

```
 auto c = add(CAM::GET_CAM_COORD(cam), multiply(rot_to_direction(&rot), speed));
```